# How to get the path or the image object from a .jpg uploaded to a server using FastAPI's UploadFile?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm importing an image using the following code:

```
files = {
    'file': open(r'C:/Users/jared/Deblur Project/curl requests/test.jpg', 'rb'),
}

response = requests.post('http://localhost:5000/net/image/evaluate_local', files=files)
print(response)
```

This sends 'test.jpg' over to the following route:

```
@app.post("/net/image/evaluate_local")

async def get_net_image_evaluate_local(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    image_path = file.read()
    threshold = 0.75
    model_path = "model.tflite"
    prediction = analyze_images(model_path, image_path, threshold)
    return prediction
```

Obviously, `image_path = file.read()` is not working, but it's showcasing what I'm trying to do. I need to provide an image path to the `analyze_images()` function, but I'm not exactly sure how to do so.

If I cannot provide it as a path, I am also trying to provide it as raw bytes array for the model to use.

```
image_path = file.read()
```

returns

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xe2\x02(ICC_PROFILE\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x02\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x10\x00\x00mntrRGB XYZ \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00acsp\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00...
```

which I am also unsure how to work with.

Anyone have any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure how to make it work as a file path, but I did manage to get it to work. Luckily the model I'm working with takes in those image bytes ( as returned by `file.read()` ).

So if I had `image = file.read()`, I could feed that image into a function that took in image as a variable, and then use it as follows:

```
img = np.uint8(tf.image.resize(tf.io.decode_image(image), [width, height], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no immediate file path because when you use FastAPI's/Starlette's [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#file-parameters-with-uploadfile),

> It uses a "spooled" file:
>
> - A file stored in memory up to a maximum size limit, and after passing this limit it will be stored in disk.

The underlying implementation is actually from Python's standard [`tempfile` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile) for generating temporary files and folders. See the [`tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile) section:

> This class operates exactly as [`TemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) does, except that data is spooled in memory until the file size exceeds `max_size`, or until the file’s `fileno()` method is called, at which point the contents are written to disk and operation proceeds as with [`TemporaryFile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile).

If you can work instead with the raw bytes of the image ([as what you did using `.read()` in your other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72037114/2745495)), then I think that's the better approach, as most image processing starts with the images bytes anyway. (Make sure to use `await` appropriately if you are calling the async methods!)

An alternative is, if a function expects a "file-like" object, then you can pass in the `UploadFile.file` object itself, which is the `SpooledTemporaryFile` object, which is the

> ... actual Python file that you can pass directly to other functions or libraries **that expect a "file-like" object**.

If you *really* need a file *on disk* and get a path to it, you can write the contents to a [`NamedTemporaryFile`'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) which

> ... is guaranteed to have a visible name in the file system (on Unix, the directory entry is not unlinked). That name can be retrieved from the name attribute of the returned file-like object.
> ...
> The returned object is always a file-like object whose file attribute is the underlying true file object. This file-like object can be used in a with statement, just like a normal file.

```
@app.post("/net/image/evaluate_local")
async def get_net_image_evaluate_local(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    file_suffix = "".join(file.filename.partition(".")[1:])
    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w+b", suffix=file_suffix) as file_on_disk:
        file_contents = await file.read()
        file_on_disk.write(file_contents)
        image_path = file_on_disk.name
        print(image_path)
        threshold = 0.75
        model_path = "model.tflite"
        prediction = analyze_images(model_path, image_path, threshold)
    return prediction
```

On my macOS, `image_path` prints out something like

```
/var/folders/3h/pdjwtnlx4p13chnw21rvwbtw0000gp/T/tmp1v52fm95.png
```

and that file would be available as long as the file is not yet closed.